# How to transform XML text received through an AJAX request into a file

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, file

I'm making an *AJAX* request to the server and getting a response as *XML text* and I've tried a bunch of ways to transform it into a downloadable file but none are working.

I've done something similar for a *pdf* but the difference is that for the *pdf* the content is returned as a blob, here's the code:

```
         $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            beforeSend: function(request) {
                request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", bearer));
            },
            url: url,
            xhrFields: {
                responseType: "blob"
            },
            success(blob) {
                var link = document.createElement("a");
                link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                link.download = "file.xml";
                link.click();
            }
        });
```

How can I **transform this code** so it works the same way when **receiving XML text**?

Comment: `request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");` makes no sense. You are making a GET request. The body has no content to describe the type of.

Comment: "How can I transform this code so it works the same way when receiving XML text?" — Do nothing. (Well, you might want to change `file.pdf` to `file.xml`). It should just work. What's the problem?

Comment: Why creating a link element? If you have an url it mimicks the same as you change the url of the current page. (Like location.href)

Comment: @Quentin you're right I removed the `request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");` even if I change the file extension the code doesn't even reach the `success` becasuse it's not a `blob`

Comment: @gramgram the idea is to automatically download the file, how would I do that using location.href?

Comment: @VítorMartins what I mean is if you create a link on the fly and click it programatically, it's the same as a redirect.

If you want a file to be downloaded and not opened within the browser, you can use **Content-Type: application/octet-stream** and **Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.xml"**. It works if you receiving the url of the xml and not the content of the xml.

Comment: @VítorMartins glad to hear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you receive the url of the XML and not the content of the XML file, you can use the headers like

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.xml"
```

It forces the browser to download the XML. You don't need to create a link on the fly and click it programatically, just open the received url by redirecting (location.href) or open in new window/tab (window.open). Latter is handy if you want to make sure to stay on the current page but restricted in some cases. Have fun!